# Java: Memory-efficient Storage for Key-Key-Value Structure - Nested Map/Key-Value Pairs

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, reinforcement-learning

In a search problem I want an agent to explore a large state space starting from an initial position, and many options to go from each visited state. I also need the agent to remember visited states and how valuable transitions from state to state were. So, given a type **S** (for State) I need a data structure to store many combinations of **S -> S -> integer** to remember how good (integer) the transition from current state (1st S) to the successor state (2nd S) was.

So far I used a Nested Hashmap like **HashMap<S, HashMap<S, Integer>>** but I am running out of memory too fast. I thought about an additional Map to assign an identifier to each state (**HashMap<S, Integer>**) and then use the identifier instead of S in the Nested Hashmap to avoid having the same state many times in the map in different triplets (since a state C could be reached from both A,B, etc.), however I am not sure if this is likely to improve anything/makes sense in theory and practically.

What would be a memory-efficient way to store such  triplets in Java? Can i expect any improvement by encoding states as integers in an additional steps?